# Probability of 2 balls selected are black and the next 2 are white

Tags: probability

An urn initially contains $5$ white and $7$ black balls. Each time a ball is selected, its color is noted and it is replaced in the urn along with $2$ other balls of the same color. Compute the probability that

$(a)$ the first $2$ balls selected are black and the next $2$ are white;

$(b)$ of the first $4$ balls selected, exactly $2$ are black.

$$ \bf \underline{My \; thoughts} $$

Denote by $A$ the event that the first 2 balls selected are black and $B$ the event that the next 2  are white. We want $P(A \cap B)$. We have

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B | A ) $$

First we find $P(A)$. Notice if first ball selected is black then prob = $\frac{7}{12}$ now we put it back with $2$ more balls which now our urn has $5$ white and $9$ black and thus this time the probability is $\frac{9}{14}$. Hence, $P(A) = \frac{7 \times 9 }{12 \times 14} $

Now we find $P(B | A)$. So we suppose $A$ has occured . well now we have $5 W $ and $11B$. Thus the third ball white gives prob $\frac{5}{16}$ and once back now we have $7W$ thus prob fourth one is white is $\frac{7}{18}$. Thus

$$ P(A \cap B) = \frac{7 \cdot 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 }{12 \cdot 14 \cdot 16 \cdot 18 } $$

Now, for part (b), we can have either $BB WW $ or $BWBW$ or $WW BB $ or $WBWB$. and we can calculate each of these event as in part (a). IS this a correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Notice you could have *immediately* found the probability for event $\sf BBWW$ (that is $A\cap B$) by using the exact same reasoning you used to evaluate each of $A,B$.   Namely that after every draw the number of balls of the colour drawn increases by 2.

So if you want the probability for drawing black exactly twice among four draws in *a particular permutation*, the numerator will contain factors of $7$ and $9$ for the black balls, and $5$ and $7$ for the white balls, in the order of the permutation, while the denominator will contain $12\cdot 14\cdot 16\cdot 18$.

And, since multiplication is commutative, thus ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea.

However, I interpret the question as if the ball is **replaced** by $2$ other balls of the same color. The total number of ball just increased by $1$ rather than $2$. But this is just a matter of English interpretation.

$$P(A)= \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{13}$$

$$P(B|A)=\frac{5}{14}\cdot \frac{6}{15}$$

Agree with part $b$. Also, by symmetric, we should have $P(BBWW)=P(BWBW)$

Edit:

You are right. I interpreted the question wrongly and missed the word "along"

Comment: It says "along with." That implies an addition of two balls overall, to me.

Comment: Ah ok, I miss the word "along"